# My BeanPostProcessor doesn't work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I wrote my BeanPostProcessor so that all methods that are marked with my **@Timing** annotation display the time of their execution in the console.

I use Spring Boot.

My **BeanPostProcessor** looks like this:

```
    import com.example.version2.annotation.Timing;
    import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

    @Component
    public class TimingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            Class type = bean.getClass();
            Method[] methods = type.getMethods();
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Timing.class)) {
                    Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(type.getClassLoader(),type.getInterfaces(), new InvocationHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                            long before = System.nanoTime();
                            Object retVal = method.invoke(bean, args);
                            long after = System.nanoTime();
                            System.out.println("Method worked: " + (after - before) + " nano seconds");
                            return retVal;
                        }
                    });
                    return proxy;
                } else {
                    return bean;
                }
            }

             return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

    }
```

This is my annotation **@Timing**:

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Timing {
}
```

I declare this annotation on one of the methods in the dao class:

```
@Timing
public  List<Map<String, Object>> selectQuery() {
    String selectQuery = prop.getMYSQL_SELECT();
    return mysqlTemplate.queryForList(selectQuery);
}
```

When the application starts, there are no problems, but when I execute the request, I see nothing in the console. It seems that BeanPostProcessor itself wrote correctly. I can not find what the error is.

I would also like to know how I can transfer this information about the time when the method is executed to the frontend in json or some List (not important).

Comment: i have never used this before, but it feels weird for me that for each annotated method you are returning a proxy class. Because it is my understanding that `Proxy.newProxyInstance` returns a class.

I wrote a timing annotation a while ago and i used spring AOP for that, it was much easier using aspects.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf thanks. Can you show example, please ?

Comment: Why not use the metrics support from Spring Boot, instead of trying to write you own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, such functionality already exists. 
Spring Boot integrates with Micrometer framework that allows this type of behavior (Spring Boot 1.x uses dropwizard metrics with an optional micrometer backport support both allow this declarative style of annotations).

[Here](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_the_timed_annotation) is a relevant chapter of micrometer documentation.

By far its the best option I know, however if you still prefer to do your own (the reason can be that all these metering frameworks maintain some mathematical model (with sliding window and everything) around the metrics, and if you want something that more resembles profiling for debugging purposes or something, then you might consider doing your own stuff).

Now a word about Spring AOP suggested by other answers. I (and this is only my opinion) think that using bean post processors has its advantage over AOP in this case.
First of all, maybe you don't use spring AOP at all, only plain spring.
The second reason to opt for this style of implementation is the performance, AOP adds quite a lot of calls to the Stack.
The obvious advantage of AOP is the simlicity of implementation.

So, let's assume you do want a BPP way:

I think first of all you should check that the Bean Post Processor gets "recognized" by spring during the application start-up.

In order to check this, you can create a no-arg consructor in BPP and print something like "Hello from BPP" there or use the debugger.

Now, regarding the suggested implementation:
You need to iterate over the methods and create a proxy only once. There is no point of creating proxy over proxy over proxy.... So the presented code is wrong.

I think you should iterate over methods, prepare a list of methods and memorize this set, then create a proxy that will have an `invoke` method that will check whether the method is in the set of methods and if so do the proxy magic, otherwise just delegate the call to the underlying bean.

Two things you should keep in mind when you go this way:

- Proxy won't work with real classes, only with the interface. If you have a class and do not work by the interface you'll need to fiddle with CGLIB
- Other bean postprocessors can also wrap your bean in some kind of proxy, for example, what if you measure a method annotated with `@Transactional`?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use aspects for this

```
@Aspect
public class TimedAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(some.thing.Timed)")
    public Object timeSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        final long before = System.nanoTime();
        final Object returnValue = joinPoint.proceed()
        final long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Method worked: " + (after - before) + " nano seconds");
        return returnValue;       
    }
}
```

Timed

```
package some.thing;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Timed {


}
```

dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

general information about spring AOP

[Spring AOP](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop)

(i have not tried if this code works, copy pasted things from a project of mine)

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through all methods but you return the bean if the first method doesn't have the `Timing` annotation:

```
for (Method method : methods) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Timing.class)) {
        Object proxy = ...
         return proxy;
     } else {
         return bean;
     }
```

This means you'll only create your custom proxy if the first method you find as the annotation.

You can get rid of the `else` clause and let your `return bean` after the for loop handle the case where no methods have the annotation.